# How to insert multiple rows (from a req. body) in a transaction

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I would like to ask if there's a way to insert multiple rows through the req. body (coming from the frontend). I have managed to create a way to insert one row, but I want to, if possible, to insert multiple rows of `task` while only inserting `job` once.

I've read that a way is to use a json array and loop it, but can't figure out how to do it. If you have another way, it would be a great help too!

I'm currently using node.js / express.js as backend, and node-postgres as connection to db.

```
//2. Declare an asynchronous function for the PG transaction
        async function execute() {
            // Promise chain for pg Pool client
            const client = await pool
                .connect()

                .catch(err => {
                    console.log("\nclient.connect():", err.name);

                    // iterate over the error object attributes
                    for (item in err) {
                        if (err[item] = undefined) {
                            process.stdout.write(item + " - " + err[item] + " ");
                        }
                    }

                    //end the Pool instance
                    console.log("\n");
                    process.exit();
                });

                try {
                    //Initiate the Postgres transaction
                    await client.query("BEGIN");

                    try {
                        const sqlString = `WITH INSERTED AS (
                            INSERT INTO jobs (job_name) VALUES
                                ($1) RETURNING id)
                            INSERT INTO tasks(
                                employee_id, job_id) VALUES
                                ($2,(
                                    SELECT id FROM inserted
                                ))`;
                        
                        const sqlValues = [job_name, employee_id
                        ];

                        // Pass SQL string to the query() method
                        await client.query(sqlString, sqlValues, function(err, result) {
                            console.log("client.query() SQL result:", result);

                            if (err) {
                            console.log("\nclient.query():", err);

                            // Rollback before executing another transaction
                            client.query("ROLLBACK");
                            console.log("Transaction ROLLBACK called");
                            } else {
                            client.query("COMMIT");
                            console.log("client.query() COMMIT row count:", result.rowCount);
                            }
                        });

                    } catch (er) {
                        // Rollback before executing another transaction
                        client.query("ROLLBACK");
                        console.log("client.query():", er);
                        console.log("Transaction ROLLBACK called");
                    }
                } finally {
                    client.release();
                    console.log("Client is released");
                }
        }

        execute();

        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err.message);
            res.status(500).send("Server Error");
    }
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure about using $1 twice when you have 2 different items to insert?

Comment: @FrankHeikens Oops, I didn't notice that typo. Thank you! Fixed (the 2nd one should be $2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a SELECT in the second INSERT and UNNEST() to get all items from the array:

```
WITH INSERTED AS (  
    INSERT INTO jobs (job_name) 
    VALUES($1) 
    RETURNING id
)
INSERT INTO tasks(employee_id, job_id) 
SELECT  UNNEST($2) -- PostgreSQL array input, you might need another function for your type of input
    ,   id
FROM inserted;
```

Edit: Example using some json-object as input:

```
WITH INSERTED AS (  
    INSERT INTO jobs (job_name) 
    VALUES($1::json #>> '{name}') -- selects the name from the json object as TEXT
    RETURNING id
)
INSERT INTO tasks(employee_id, job_id) 
SELECT  column1 
    ,   id
FROM inserted
    , json_to_recordset($1::json #> '{tasks}') AS t(column1 int, column2 text);
```

$1 is a single json-object that is used twice. PostgreSQL will extract the elements that are needed for the INSERTs.

Comment: hi, apologies, but can you explain how unnest works? I've read the documentation and checked other resources and it's still a bit fuzzy for me.

Please correct me if I'm wrong but from what I understand, I can use ```unnest``` to open the array of objects (json) from req.body.

How should I format my array? I read that it should be
```"arrayName":[{ "Row1col1: "Row1value1", "Row1col2": "Row1value2" }.
{"Row2col1": "Row2value1", "Row2col2": "Row2val2"}]```

Thank you and apologies if the question might be something I easily missed while reading documentation.

Comment: @TechArtificer: Could you show us a valid json object?

Comment: Here's the [JSON](https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=cloud.90d87d826414474db2847572f18c1a5e) I'm planning to send to the db via the req.body. The example in the JSON assumes that the data inserted will have multiple columns instead of only one (contrary to the code I posted above) and with different data-type (int and string), just in case I might need it in the future as additional reference.

Comment: @TechArtificer: See new example, using just a single input parameter, the complete json object that you showed us.

Comment: Hello, I "think" it's working as I'm able to read and accept the json, but I'm having an error that says ```'Expected ":", but found "}".``` I checked googled and it appears to be a problem with [node-pg as described in this issue](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/442), I'm tried using JSON.stringify on the sqlValues ```tasks``` but it's still returning the error.

Thanks for your help! Erm, if I may ask, would it be possible to put conditions in the transaction? e.g. You can't insert the same employee_id twice, or check if employee_id already exists in the table?

Comment: Yes, that's possible, use a unique constraint on the table column and a ON CONFLICT solution in the INSERT to catch these expected errors.

Comment: I see, alright, will check on that after this one. Update on the situation, I managed to send the query successfully, although it inserted nothing from array. I console.log the array and its values are there. Anything I can do to debug?

Comment: IDK if this is helpful but it seems like it can "read" the JSON no problem, as I tried to put a wrong data type (insert a String in an INT column) and it called an error saying it's not allowed.

Comment: EDIT: False alarm, it does not prompt an error, please ignore the comment above this.

Comment: UPDATE: IT WORKS NOW. After reading some discussions over Stackoverflow, I removed ```#>> 'tasks'```, and then let $1 point directly to the req. body value 'name' instead of pointing at JSON.

Thank you for answering my questions earlier! It really helped me get the final solution. Thank you!